# c# method returning IEnumerable<dynamic> gets cast as dynamic if I use a params object

Tags: c#, razor

I am wrapping up the database helper for razor so that I can do some logging and other stuff when db queries are run.

I was using the params object[] as an overload to pass in any parameters for the query and the method looks something like this;

```
public IEnumerable<dynamic> Query(string sql, params object[] paramsList)
{
    var db = Database.Open("myDBHere");
    var queryResult = db.Query(sql, paramsList);

    return queryResult;

}
```

When I return the object it shows as dynamic not `IEnumerable<dynamic>`. If I use a list to pass in the parameters then create an array from the list, it returns `IEnumerable<dynamic>`;

```
public IEnumerable<dynamic> Query2(string sql, List<string> paramslist)
{

    var paramsArray = paramslist.ToArray();
    var db = Database.Open("myDBHere");
    var queryResult = db.Query(sql, paramsArray);
    
    return queryResult;

}
```

But this means I am passing in all strings. The rest of the method is identical and in the class file the return variable is shown as `IEnumerable<dynamic>` in the IDE for both methods.

Anyone have any ideas..?

UPDATE - This behaviour is only exhibited if you use a dynamic type in the params Object[] passed to the method.

I was using the AppState to store some stuff and setting and accessing them via the shortcut App.KEYNAME that makes use of dynamic properties. If I used AppState["KEYNAME"] everything worked as expected.

Comment: Further investigation shows me that this only happens if one of the values I pass in the params list is a dynamic itself

Comment: More information. I was using AppState to store some global stuff and using the shortcut App.KEYNAME to set and access the AppState keys. When used in conjunction with the params Object[] it resulted in the loss of the IEnumerable properties. If I use AppState["keyname"] IEnumerable is returned. I cant explain this though so perhaps someone else could.

Comment: dynamic is synonymous with object with the added caveat that the DLR comes into play. Once used, everything has to be considered to possibly be dynamic as well. The DLR then figures everything out at runtime (essentially starting a version of the C# compiler), tracking individual callsites as the dynamic *spreads*. Personally I'd advise against using dynamic if you can find a better way (just use object directly if necessary) as unless you're calling methods/properties *directly* on the objects (without type check/casting) then it's sort of pointless

Comment: The minute that one of the parameters is dynamic, then overload resolution has to happen at runtime rather than compile-time (since the types of the parameters affect which overload is chosen). Once overload resolution is at runtime, the compiler doesn't know what type is going to be returned (different overloads could return different types), and so the return type has to be dynamic as well. It doesn't matter if there only happens to be 1 overload: the same rules apply

Comment: Thanks @pinkfloydx33 I am starting to learn about the pitfalls of dynamic objects =)

Comment: @canton7 makes sense, thank you. Should I answer this question or will it just get closed now..?

Comment: I linked it to another question with the same answer, all good!

Comment: @RolfHerbert you tagged this question as Razor Pages. In fact you are using the old Web Pages framework. They are not the same thing. One of the reasons that Web Pages  never really took off was it relied too much on the dynamic type.